# Only allow values that are not in the range

Tags: email, google-apps-script, scripting, google-sheets

I'm making a list with emails for a newsletter, the emails are taken directly from the gmail inbox and pasted into the Sheet. However there are some emails i want to black-list from adding to the main column of mails.

I wanted to add the black-listed mails to another column and use requireValueInRange from the DatavalidationBuilder in some way to say "if the value appears in range B then dont be able to add it to range A"

I want to do the opposite of this:

```
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B1:B10');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `requireFormulaSatisfied` to achieve your goal. Refer the below code.

```
   function setRule(){
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied("=NOT(EQ(A1,B1:B10))").build();
       cell.setDataValidation(rule);
     }
```